# Can we use testing tool like selenium, Appium to automate some user task in android App?

Tags: android, selenium, automation, appium, audio-player, android-music-player

For now, I am working on selenium in a company . I am making a tool which will automate timesheet filling process by using **Selenium**,**Sikuli**. It is web application based automation.

But I want to know that how we can automate some process in android Apps? 
For Example:If I want to automate like 
1.)if user click on favourite songs in **Music Player** then it will automatically start to play favourite songs or 
2.)if user click on recent playing songs then it start to play recent songs automatically.

I searched on internet about it then I found that **Appium** is used as an **automation tool** for testing of **mobile application**.

Please let me know that I am on the right track. If not, Please suggest some other way or tool with which I can automate user task in android App.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. Appium can perform these user tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Espresso testing framework, provided by the `Android Testing Support Library`, provides APIs for writing UI tests to simulate user interaction.
You can automate your UI testing.

You can find various examples and documentation here https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/index.html

Comment: Ok, I will check it out. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @kamal kumar If it helped and worked for you please accept the answer :)

Comment: Yeah , sure . I will accept the answer if it will solve my problem.

Comment: @kamalkumar which tool did you start using ?

Comment: Hey for now , I am busy to learn something.So will do this part on this weekend. How can i accept your answer?

Comment: you can accept the answer as you have asked the question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers